# How to refactor similar code in conditional statements?

Tags: c#

I wanted to refactor this big piece of bloated code ,I feel like there is a better way to rewrite this. Does anyone have idea of how to do it?

```
if (ls.SelectedIndex == 1) { grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }
...
if (ls.SelectedIndex == 58) { grid58.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create array of Grid

```
var gridArray = new Grid[N];
```

Fill it:

```
gridArray[1] = grid1;
gridArray[2] = grid2;
...
```

Use:

```
gridArray[ls.SelectedIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: You have to make sure to check for -1 selectedIndex or you will run into an error